# How to align rows at bottom of the screen along with other containers at top

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve a UI in which there are 2 buttons in the center and then afterwards there are 2 rows at the bottom of the screen fixed respective to screen sizes I will stay at its place, but I'm unable to do it in my case I'm using Column and all the other containers and rows are in it.

> Desired Result on emulator is fine

[image: Demo Image]

> What I am getting in real device

[image: Result Image]

Here is the code.

```
class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF29F76),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/intropage.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 550,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignUpPage()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 180,
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign Up",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 650,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignInPage()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 180,
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign In",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xFFFE6B01)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 750,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 2,
                        width: 150,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "  Please Read  ",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 2,
                        width: 150,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 760,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 6),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        TermsandConditions()));
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "Terms & Conditions",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 6),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => PrivacyPolicy()));
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "Privacy Policy",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've failed to identify the issue on images ? can you mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method its will do the job. Background image will appear and you can align your widgets using the Alignment property

```
class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        image: AssetImage(
          'assets/intropage.png',
        ),
      )),
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 250.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignUpPage()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 180,
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign Up",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 500.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignInPage()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 180,
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign In",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xFFFE6B01)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 2,
                        width: 150,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "  Please Read  ",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 2,
                        width: 150,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 6),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => TermsandConditions()));
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "Terms & Conditions",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 6),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => PrivacyPolicy()));
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "Privacy Policy",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your widgets inside

```
  Positioned(
     Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: _your_widget_here()
```

Comment: Didn't worked the row went on top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommanded to use fix value for the layout.
Stack here it's not necessary.
A simple Spacer Widget can the work. But there are multiple way to do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF29F76),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              "assets/intropage.png",
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const SignUpPage()));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 180,
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        borderRadius:
                        const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign Up",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const SignInPage()));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 180,
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        borderRadius:
                        const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign In",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Color(0xFFFE6B01)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 2,
                  width: 150,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "  Please Read  ",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 2,
                  width: 150,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 6),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  TermsandConditions()));
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      "Terms & Conditions",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 6),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => PrivacyPolicy()));
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      "Privacy Policy",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Spacer is giving NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE error. When I remove it the ui appears but the containers are too far distant at bottom looks very odd and for the text to appear I've to scroll down on a 6.4 inch device

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can use standard buttons, use them. I used ElevatedButton with custom styles, so please check it.
2. In general it is a bad idea to add accumulated top padding to each element. Screens sizes are different and your layout will be failed on another screen size.
   Please see my example of how to do this better.
3. Also I added other small improvements, maybe you will be interested in.

```dart
class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _createButton({
    required VoidCallback onPressed,
    required Widget child,
    required Color textColor,
  }) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: child,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        elevation: 0.0,
        primary: Colors.white,
        onPrimary: textColor,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
        ),
        fixedSize: Size(180.0, 60.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF29F76),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 400.0, //your image height
                      child: Image.network(
                        "https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/61DiwECVps74bWazF88Cy9/2cc9411d050b8ca50530cf97b3e51c96/Image_Cover.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        _createButton(
                          child: Text("Sign Up"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                //your page
                                builder: (context) => Container(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                        _createButton(
                          child: Text("Sign In"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                //your page
                                builder: (context) => Container(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          textColor: Color(0xFFFE6B01),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            _BottomSection(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BottomSection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Divider(
                height: 2,
                thickness: 2,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text(
              "Please Read",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Expanded(
              child: Divider(
                height: 2,
                thickness: 2,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 6.0,
            right: 20.0,
            left: 20.0,
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Container()));
                },
                child: const Text(
                  "Terms & Conditions",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Container()));
                },
                child: const Text(
                  "Privacy Policy",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```